# Convert from Epoch to DateTime in AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I would like to use AMPscript to convert an epoch date into the following format: MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt (eg. April 30, 2018 1:05 PM)

Is this possible with AMPscript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After some research, it doesn't look like AMPScript is able to easily convert Epoch Dates.  In this case, I would utilize SSJS to handle it.

Sample using the value from your comment:

```
<script runat="server">
  Platform.Load('Core','1');

  var utcSeconds = 1525057527200;

  var d = new Date(utcSeconds); // The 0 there is the key, which sets the date to the epoch

  Write(d);
</script>
```

This will output `4/29/2018 9:05:27 PM`

If you need to move it into AMPScript, you can use the following SSJS function: [SetValue(1, 2)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformAMPscriptVariableSetValue.htm)

which would make the following:

```
<script runat="server">
  Platform.Load('Core','1');

  var utcSeconds = 1525057527200;

  var d = new Date(utcSeconds); // The 0 there is the key, which sets the date to the epoch

  Platform.Variable.SetValue("@date",d); 
  //Sets the AMPScript variable @date to the value of SSJS var 'd'
</script>

%%[

   SET @formattedDate = FORMATDATE(@date, "MM/DD/YYYY")

]%%
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply! Unfortunately I'm not getting the desired result.

Comment: I tried %%=FormatDate(1525057527200, "MMMM dd, yyyy", "h:mm tt", "en-US")=%% and am getting nothing returned. Have you successfully used this script for Unix Epoch date format?

Comment: @Lauren Edited my answer as AMPScript format functions do not work on Epoch dates.